# How to enable /disable internet browser extensions using java

Tags: java, web, browser, microsoft-edge

I am writing a program where I need to make a button to enable and disable the browser extensions from application only. Need your help in that.

I am able to get the list of extensions from the browsers manifest. Json file but I am not aware how to enable and disable those extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you are not able to enable/disable extensions using Java. Extensions are part of user preferences and browser UI so you can't disable them via a button in the application. If you need to disable any extension, you can create an extension to disable another extension.

**Update**: After some investigations, I've figured out how third-party applications disable browser extensions. Take CCleaner as an example. If you need to disable/enable an extension, you need to close the browser first. That is because CCleaner simply overwrites the `Preference` file in your profile folder and adds/deletes `"disable_reasons": 1`, which turns off/on the extension. You can manually do the same, but it only works with the browser closed. If that is what you want, you've got it.

**Example**

Extension turned off:

```
"settings": {
       "TargetExtensionID": {
            "disable_reasons": 1
}
```

Extension turned on:

```
"settings": {
       "TargetExtensionID": {

}
```

Comment: Then How CCleaner and other similar applications disables and enables the browser extensions ?

Comment: @vijaykumar, I've done some investigations and updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks Li let me try this will let you know about the results.

Comment: Thanks a million Li it worked and I also tried to update the preference file while Google Chrome was open and to my surprise that also worked but to see the effect i just closed and opened the chrome and extension was disabled.